# Ejecutar un script en Python con Crontab

Tags: python, crontab, cron

necesito ejecutar un script que esta programado en Python para que este se ejecute cada cierto tiempo, especificamente cada 3 minutos. Estoy utilizando crontab y el archivo que modifique fue el siguiente:

**crontab -e**

Dentro de ese archivo el contenido que coloque es el siguiente:

```
    #M      H       D       DS      M
    */3     *       *       *       *       /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log
    0       0       *       *       *       /usr/local/nagios/bin/sched_downtime
```

Si yo ejecuto el archivo manualmente por separado se ejecuta de manera correcta. ¿De que manera puedo correrlo cada 3 minutos?

El log del cron ubicado en la siguiente ruta /var/log/cron es el siguiente:

```
Jun 21 16:23:35 ip-172-31-8-52 crond[2641]: (CRON) STARTUP (1.4.4)
Jun 21 16:23:35 ip-172-31-8-52 crond[2641]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 17% if used.)
Jun 21 16:23:35 ip-172-31-8-52 crond[2641]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Jun 21 16:24:02 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[2794]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 16:27:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[3222]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 16:30:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[3605]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 16:33:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[3982]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 16:36:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[4362]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 16:39:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[4739]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 16:42:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[5119]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 16:45:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[5495]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 16:48:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[5911]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 16:51:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[6285]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 16:54:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[6670]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 16:57:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[7044]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 17:00:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[7425]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 17:01:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[7515]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 21 17:01:01 ip-172-31-8-52 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[7515]: starting 0anacron
Jun 21 17:01:01 ip-172-31-8-52 anacron[7525]: Anacron started on 2018-06-21
Jun 21 17:01:01 ip-172-31-8-52 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[7527]: finished 0anacron
Jun 21 17:01:01 ip-172-31-8-52 anacron[7525]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 14 min.
Jun 21 17:01:01 ip-172-31-8-52 anacron[7525]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Jun 21 17:03:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[7815]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 17:06:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[8198]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 17:09:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[8574]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 17:12:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[8960]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 17:15:01 ip-172-31-8-52 anacron[7525]: Job `cron.daily' started
Jun 21 17:15:01 ip-172-31-8-52 run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[9368]: starting logrotate
Jun 21 17:15:01 ip-172-31-8-52 run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[9376]: finished logrotate
Jun 21 17:15:01 ip-172-31-8-52 run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[9368]: starting man-db.cron
Jun 21 17:15:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[9386]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 17:15:01 ip-172-31-8-52 run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[9396]: finished man-db.cron
Jun 21 17:15:01 ip-172-31-8-52 run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[9368]: starting tmpwatch
Jun 21 17:15:01 ip-172-31-8-52 run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[9422]: finished tmpwatch
Jun 21 17:15:01 ip-172-31-8-52 anacron[7525]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Jun 21 17:15:01 ip-172-31-8-52 anacron[7525]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Jun 21 17:18:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[9798]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 17:21:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[10229]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
Jun 21 17:24:01 ip-172-31-8-52 CROND[10817]: (nagios) CMD (/usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log)
```

La salida del log es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: antepones la palabra python , `python /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.py >> /usr/local/nagios/nan/mailer/mailer.log`

Comment: O por si acaso, mejor la ruta completa hasta el ejecutable python, delante del nombre del script. Por ejemplo `/usr/bin/python /usr/local/.../mailer.py`

Comment: y si tienes dudas donde esta python  escribes en consola  `which python` , copias la ruta y actualizas el ejemplo de @abulafia

Comment: Realice la modificación colocando la ruta completa en donde esta instalado Python, pero hasta el momento sin ningún resultado .

Comment: Hay errores en /var/log/syslog ?

Comment: Hola, el log es el siguiente: /var/log/cron y no se muestra ningun error.

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez si corría tu script pero como no está como ejecutable ni tenía un *shebang*, entonces no hacía nada.

En ese caso, y si quieres intentarlo, tendrías que poner al inicio de tu archivo mailer.py algo como.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
...
todo el código python que hiciste
...
```

Y le das permisos de ejecución con `chmod +x mailer.py`.
Y tu crontab ya debería correr con la simple ruta del archivo de mailer.py, tal como lo mostraste en tu pregunta.

Para ver los logs de una tarea programada con `crontab` puedes revisar el archivo `/var/log/syslog` así.

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep "CRON"
```

Entonces los puedes ver en tiempo "real".

En caso de que quieras crear un archivo de errores, al momento de crear un crontab tendrías que redireccionar la salida de lo ejecutado por el script, por ejemplo.

```
*/3 * * * * programa 2>> /ruta/a/error.log
```

o

```
*/3 * * * * programa >> /ruta/a/all.log 2>&1
```

Con este último tanto *stdout* como *stdin* van al archivo de errores.

Otra opción es, como te sugieren en los comentarios, que tienes que poner qué programa va a correr ese archivo, pensando en que no le pusiste un *shebang*. A mi me ha funcionado simplemente poniendo algo el estilo `python /ruta/completa/del/archivo.py` o con un `cd /carpeta/del/archivo && python archivo.py`, es decir, no he tenido problemas con la localización de `python` puesto que en la documentación de `man crontab(5)` se establece lo siguiente.

> Several environment variables are set up automatically by the cron(8) daemon.  SHELL is set to `/bin/sh`,  and  LOGNAME  and HOME  are set from the `/etc/passwd` line of the crontab's owner. PATH is set to `/usr/bin:/bin`. HOME, SHELL, and PATH may be overridden by settings in the crontab; LOGNAME is the user that the job is running from, and may not be changed.

Y como tengo `python` localizado en `/usr/bin/python`, no tengo problema. Para localizarlo no uses `which`, usa `command -v python` puesto que `which` solo revisa si está en tu `PATH` pero `command` devuelve la forma en que `bash` interpreta ese comando, y, dentro de un script, muestra la ruta completa de ese programa.

En caso de que estés en modo paranoico (se que a veces uno se pone supersticioso) puedes correr el crontab con.

```
*/3 * * * * /donde/esta/tu/python /archivo/a/correr.py
```

Otra opción que puedes utilizar es crear un script en bash que sea un wrapper.

Por ejemplo.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:~/bin  #O el PATH que quieras para ese wrapper.
_LOG_FILE=/ruta/a/registro.log
_LOG_ERROR_FILE=/ruta/a/error.log

#Puedes añadir más cosas a tu wrapper para turbo personalizar tus logs
#o forma de llamar a tus programas.

python /la/ruta/a/tu/programa.py >> $_LOG_FILE 2>> $_LOG_ERROR_FILE
# o puedes hacer algo como
python /ruta/programa.py > >(tee -a $_LOG_FILE) 2> >(tee -a $_LOG_ERROR_FILE >&2)
```

Al terminar de editar este *wrapper* necesitas darle **permisos de ejecución** con `chmod +x tu_wrapper`

Y ahora puedes correr tu tarea programada con la simple ruta del wrapper y de forma personalizada. Ya se puede ejecutar, ya tiene el *shebang* entonces ya se sabe que se tiene que ejecutar con `/bin/bash`, tiene el `PATH` que quieras y tiene un manejo de registros.

```
*/3 * * * * /ruta/a/tu/wrapper
```